# How to give margin to a div without moving elements?

Tags: html, css

i would like to move my header content text to the center without moving the header img / rest of elements.
In the next image you can see my .portada-text and .portada botones above at the top **behind my nav**. I drew in paint white boxes where i would like where my div elements be.
I tried moving them with **padding and/or margin** in the father div (#portada) or each div child (.portada-text and .portada-botones) but it moves the image or expand the screen to the bottom and i just want to move those divs without moving the rest of elements...

[image]

My HTML

```
<section class="portada" id="portada">
    <div class="portada-texto">
        <h1>Hola, soy Diego Donoso</h1>
        <h2>Técnico Analista Programador</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="portada-botones">
        <button>Leer más</button>
        <button>Contáctame</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

My CSS

```
#portada{
    min-height: 100vh; /*usará todo el tamaño del largo dependiendo de la pantalla*/
    background-image: url(../images/banner1.webp); /*imagen de fondo*/
    background-size: cover; /*la imagen se expande a la pantalla*/
    background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30); /*color de imagen*/
    background-blend-mode: soft-light; /*tono de color de portada*/
    text-align: center;
}

#portada .portada-texto {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
}

#portada .portada-texto h1,h2{
   color: white;
   font-size: 2em;
}

#portada .portada-botones button{
   color: white;
   background: #ff9800;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   font-size: 1.625em; /*26px*/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree completely with Vincent here, this looks like a job for something like:

```
.classNameOfElementsToMove {
position: relative;
left: 100px;
}
```

This will move all elements with the class 100px to the right (adjust as necessary to your own liking) without affecting the other elements. Do note though that (although I think this won't matter in your case) the elements will still take up space in the flow of the page as if they were in their normal position.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this reference for different positioning schemes:
[Mozilla: position - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

By default, all elements are static and if you change their margin/padding you'll inherently increase the width and height of the entire element. You can also change the left and right properties, but that doesn't do anything if the elements are static.

Basically you'll want **relative** which will allow you to position elements based on where they would naturally be set and it "does not affect the position of any other elements; thus, the space given for the element in the page layout is the same as if position were static".

Comment: thank you bro, i'll study and practice more about positions...